# How to change the value of search input box to the user input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

Here is the code

```
<form class="navbar-search pull-right header-link" method="post" name="searchportlet" id="searchportlet" onsubmit="window.location.href='/s.nl?ext=F&amp;sc=22&amp;category=&amp;search='+escape(document.forms['searchportlet'].elements['search'].value);return false;">
    <div class="dowith clearfix">
        <a href="#" class="left" onclick="window.location.href='/s.nl?ext=F&sc=22&category=&search='+escape(document.forms['searchportlet'].elements['search'].value);return false; return false;">
            <img alt="" src="/images/search.png" style="margin-top: 5px;">
        </a>
        <input name="search" type="text" onsubmit="window.location.href='/s.nl?ext=F&sc=22&category=&search='+escape(document.forms['searchportlet'].elements['search'].value);return false; return false;" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search entire store...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search entire store...';}" value="Search entire store..." class="right textfield" id="search_input">
    </div><!--End dowith-->
</form>
```

How to retain the search input text entered by user. I need the solution in js or jquery.after form submit search entire store value must replace by the text input by the user

Comment: *retain* when? where? why ?

Comment: i have tried this script but its not working<script type="text/javascript">
var yq = $.noConflict();
yq('#search_input').submit(function() {
  var txt = yq('#search_input');
  txt.val("updated " + txt.val());
});</script>

Comment: Do you mean, after the form has been submitted, the page refreshed and the search returns, then the search box retains the original search string.

Comment: no the search string input by the user should be there

Comment: @user1881845 - Your question is very hard to understand.  Please take a moment and explain the setup, the expected behavior and the actual behavior in detail.  Something like: 1) I load the page 2) I enter a value in the "search" input field 3) I submit the form 4) Expected behavior: Previously entered value shows in "search" input field 5) Actual behavior: Previously entered value does NOT show in "search" input field.

Comment: http://shopping.netsuite.com/seltec this is the website when we search a product it displays the result but the text input by the user removed i want to show the user entered text after hitting enter

Comment: This is exactly what @PatDobson suggested above.  To do this, you don't need Javascript or jQuery.  This needs to be handled on the server side by giving the input field the attribute `value="My entered search string"`

Comment: After you perform your search, the URL is as follows: http://shopping.netsuite.com/s.nl?ext=F&sc=22&category=&search=something - Therefore (server side) get the value of 'search' and use that to populate the search field, as @Steve says. No need for any javascript . . .

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your site, there is this section which gets executed after your page has been loaded:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

add something like this below it:

```
$('#search_input').val(location.href.split('&search=')[1] || '');
```

This is not a good solution (basically reads the URL and picks search term if exists).
If you can edit server-side code, better handle it there.

Comment: oddly jQuery is not working now on your site. anyway add this at the end of your document and tell me if it works? `<script>document.getElementById('search_input').value = location.href.split('&search=')[1] || '';</script>`

Comment: i have write this <script type="text/javascript">
var yq = $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(yq) {
yq('#search_input').submit(function() {
yq('#search_input').val(location.href.split('&search=')[1] || '');
});
});</script> is it ok?

Comment: no put as first line of `ready` function:
`jQuery(document).ready(function(yq) { yq('#search_input').val(location.href.split('&search=')[1] || ''); })`